# express $\sum_{n=1}^{135} (1-i)^n$ in standard form, Complex numbers

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, summation

How would you state $\sum_{n=1}^{135} (1-i)^n$ in standard form.

in polar form $(1-i)$ can be expressed as $\sqrt2(\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})$ and also through De Moivre's Thereom this can be expressed as $\sqrt2(\cos(\frac{3n\pi}{4})+i\sin(\frac{3n\pi}{4})$ But from here im not sure how i would apply the sums to 135

Comment: I'd suggest trying number 7 from here http://www.mathwords.com/f/factoring_rules.htm

Comment: $\sqrt2(\cos({3\pi\over4})+i\sin({3\pi\over4}))=-1+i$, not $1-i$.

Answer (score 2):

One has for $q\neq 1$

$$\sum_{n=1}^Nq^n=q\cdot{1-q^N\over 1-q}$$

Replace $q$ with $1-i =\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi\over 4}$. One gets

$$\sum_{n=1}^N(1-i)^N=(1-i){1-(1-i)^N\over i}$$

Comment: is this a theorem?

Comment: It is just the sum of the first terms of a geometric series

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the sum of a finite geometric series gives
$$S:=\sum_{k=1}^{135}(1-i)^k=(1+i)\bigl((1-i)^{135}-1\bigr)\ .$$
Now $(1-i)=2^{1/2}\>e^{-i\pi/4}$ and therefore 
$$(1-i)^{135}=2^{135/2}\>e^{-135i\pi/4} =2^{67}\>e^{-34i\pi}\cdot 2^{1/2}e^{i\pi/4}=2^{67}\>(1+i)\ .$$
It follows that
$$S=(1+i)\bigl(2^{67}(1+i)-1\bigr)=-1+\bigl(2^{68}-1\bigr)i\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{n=0}^{N} r^n = \frac{r^N-1}{r-1} $

so

$\sum_{n=1}^{N} r^n = \frac{r^N-1}{r-1}-r^0 = \frac{r^N-r}{r-1}$

so

$\sum_{n=1}^{135} (1-i)^n =  \frac{(1-i)^{135}-(1-i)}{(1-i)-1} = i((1-i)^{135}-1+i) = (1+i)((1-i)^{134}-1)= (1+i)(2^{67}e^{i\frac{3}{4}\pi*134}-1)$